# Why does Mat.forEach doesn't change itself?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

Basically, I'm trying to use less pixels to represent an image itself.

The steps are below:

1. Say I will input an image with size [1000*600], then I got 600_000 pixels(rgb), which could be [600_000, 3] vectors. **K-Means** is used to get its cluster centers.
2. The each pixel in the image will be placed with its nearest neighbor among the clusters found via K-Means.

The source is:

```
template <typename T>
void NN(Point3_<T>& pixel, const Mat& points)
{
    vector<T> vt {pixel.x, pixel.x, pixel.z};
    double min_dist = LDBL_MAX;
    int min_index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.rows; ++ i)
    {
        double dist = norm(vt, points.row(i), NORM_L2);
        if (dist < min_dist) 
        {
            min_dist = dist;
            min_index = i;
        }
    }
    // assert(min_index != -1);
    pixel.x = points.at<T>(min_index, 0);
    pixel.y = points.at<T>(min_index, 1);
    pixel.z = points.at<T>(min_index, 2);
}

template <typename T>
void NN(Mat& img, const Mat& points)
{
    timer::start("assign");
    img.forEach<Point3_<T>>([&points](Point3_<T> &pixel, const int position[])
        {
            NN(pixel, points);
        });
    timer::stop<ms>();
}

Mat kmeans(const Mat& original_img, const int K)
{
    Mat img;
    original_img.reshape(3, original_img.rows * original_img.cols)
        .convertTo(img, CV_32FC3);

    timer::start("K-means cluster");
    // Require img.type() == CV_32F
    Mat clusters = BOWKMeansTrainer(K).cluster(img);
    timer::stop<ms>();

    // Type 5 -> Type 0: 32FC1 -> 8UC1
    // K rows, 3 cols, 8UC1
    clusters.convertTo(clusters, CV_8UC1);
    Mat output_img = original_img;
    NN<uchar>(output_img, clusters);

    // assert won't fire, why?
    assert(equal(original_img.begin<uchar>(), original_img.end<uchar>(),
        output_img.begin<uchar>()));

    return output_img;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    vector<int> ks {2, 16};
    string filename = "1";
    string pathname = string("./img/") + filename + ".jpg";

    Mat img = imread(pathname);
    for (const int& K: ks)
    {
        imshow(int_to_string(K), kmeans(img, K));
        // write_img(filename, "kmeans", K, kmeans(img, K));
    }

    std::cout << "Press enter to continue...";
    cin.get();
}
```

The questions are:

1. The **assert()** in kmeans() won't fire. That is, the mat object **original_img** is identical to **output_img**. How could this happen?
2. The two **imwrite()** in main() will show two identical 2-value images. That is, the K-Means with K=2 works, while the following with K=16 **does not**. Note that if we output one image per execution, everything is fine.

The buggy output is below:

[image: The buggy output]

The original image and K-Means with K=16 could be seen below:

[image: The original image]

[image: K-Means with K=16]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank god! I've found the cause.

In kmeans(), the below code will call Mat's copy constructor, which costs O(1) to assign original_img's header to output_img's.

```
Mat output_img = original_img;
```

This is the reason why the assert won't fire.